# compiler error for moveItemAtURL in Swift contradicts Apple docs

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I am trying to call NSFileManager.moveItemAtURL in Swift, but get the error below.
Seems lik I am using the right syntax??  I'm stumped

```
// From Apple documentation

// func moveItemAtURL(srcURL: NSURL!, toURL dstURL: NSURL!, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool

NSFileManager.moveItemAtURL(oldDocumentURL, toURL: newDocumentURL, error :nil)

// Error: Extra agrument 'toURL' in call
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to pass the parameter names. "toURL" and "error" are not needed. Try

```
NSFileManager.moveItemAtURL(oldDocumentURL, newDocumentURL, nil)
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its an instance method so you need to run through the `defaultManager` Singleton instance

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(oldDocumentURL, toURL: newDocumentURL, error: nil)`
```

or any other instance in specialised cases, for example `NSFilePresenter`

```
let manager = NSFileManager()

manager.moveItemAtURL(oldDocumentURL, toURL: newDocumentURL, error: nil)
```